# Magento 2 Security Updates APSB22-38 Patch

Tags: magento2, security-patch

Currently, we are using the Adobe Commerce Enterprise Version 2.4.3 P1. We are just notified about the Security Updates for APSB22-38 (CVE-2022-34253).

We didn't find any patches available for these updates.Usually we get patches along with the security update.
Does it required to update the Magento version to 2.4.3-p3?
Or Can/Will we get any patches for our current version?

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

There is no patch for this security update. You have to update to the 2.4.3-p3 to apply the fix.

https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/magento/apsb22-38.html